# Questions on torque calculation - on topic or not?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are a few questions around which concern torque calculations for different applications.  I was wondering if those questions are actually on topic for EE as it is mainly a mechanical problem to calculate the needed torque.

I can see that there wasn't a good place to ask such questions before, but with the new [Engineering Stackexchange](http://engineering.stackexchange.com) I'd say there is a better place to ask those questions now.

I tried to flag a [new question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/189532/conveyor-system-torque-calculation) to be moved there, but it's not available to select in the list to move to (only SuperUser and Meta showed up, maybe I'm not aware on how to select other pages?). So maybe this might be added as a "move to"-site as well?

Comment: If it were a good question I could see migrating it, but it's a crappy question, so we close it and move on.

Answer (score 2):

Beta sites can't be the target of a close menu.

This question is clearly off topic. It should be closed.

Should it be migrated? No, it's not a great question and Engineering.SE is a beta site.

Comment: The other questions went through the net then? Or why is this [question (calculating the torque)](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9639/calculating-the-amount-of-torque-needed-to-turn-shutter) open, up-voted and answered? I can see why [What is torque](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27931/torque-kgcm-what-is-kgcm) might be good to have here as EE come across this specification. Even in beta, shouldn't we try to get people to EG.SE (so it gets more popular and the beta comes to a positive end)?

Comment: @Arsenal a Beta site doesn't just need questions, it needs active users. Tossing our garbage over the fence does no favors to a small and growing site. Saying you want to calculate the torque needed by a motor is a fairly tenuous link to EE.